# Disable the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have an input field. In which I want to fix a value. I am able to fix the value by putting readonly but it's not passing the value which I have put as fixed.

what I am doing is:-

```
<input name="txt_zip_code" class="z-con-input adj-z-con-input" style="background:#eee"  type="text"  maxlength="13" field="txt_zip_code" value="98052" readonly="readonly" />
```

I want to make the value same for every user.

Can I get any help in this.

Comment: `it's not passing the value with I have put as fixed`, so what does it actually pass?

Comment: @ekad it gives a validation error.

Comment: *passing the value* to where? If the value is hard coded, put it already in the destination...

Comment: How does the validation error happen? On submitting the form?

Comment: It's like I have 3 input fields: Order Number, PO Number and Billing Zip Code. User is having option either he can put order number OR PO number. And there is a fixed value for zip code which is common for every user and required for order number and po number.

Comment: I assume you are validating with JS/jQ? How are you validating the value? `$("input[name='txt_zip_code']").val()`? What does that return?

Comment: @RohitMehra Why not put all relevant infos in question? You'd have better to explain what are you looking for

Comment: Pulling the val from jQuery works just fine: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g43et2qn/)

Answer (score 0):

You have not included what back end system you are using, which is relevant information. However, with PHP and ASP.NET MVC I've discovered a similar behavior. I believe you are describing disabled/readonly inputs sending `null` values to the back end controller. In the past, I've found that I had to re-enable inputs with Javascript before submitting them to the controller. The jquery to do this is:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("input").removeProp('readonly');
$("form").submit();
});
```

However, if the field is always static, you may just want to hard code it on the back end.

I'd also recommend you check out the [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html) on disabled elements to make sure the readonly attribute is the correct attribute for you. You are currently using the readonly attribute incorrectly, as it is a boolean attribute.

```
<input readonly="readonly">
```

should be:

```
<input readonly>
```